# Is it possible to bypass stat_smooth when using geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set that I have built the following plot around:
[image]

The plot is fed from a data set included at the bottom of this post, and is made from the following ggplot2 code:

```
    ggFacetProfile <- ggplot(sub, aes(group = iMoYr))  + 
    geom_line(aes(x= iHrMi, y = trimAv)) + 
    facet_grid(off ~ iMoYr, scales = "free") +
    ggtitle("Typical Half Hourly Profiles") + 
    xlab("Time") + ylab("Energy (kWh)")
```

Here I am plotting the values `trimAv` (effectively average values) over `iHrMi` (effectively hour and minute). This is on a facet of `off` by `iMoYr` (effectively is the process on of off, and different months over the year).

The data table already has the effective smoothed value ranges calculated in it, under the heading `minEcl` and `maxEcl`. I would like to be able to use geom_smooth to represent this data on the graph as boundaries of the shape made by the function geom_smooth, however I haven't been able to locate a way to bypass calling stat_smooth.

My closest attempt so far is to include:

```
+ geom_smooth(aes(x= iHrMi, y = trimAv, ymin = minEcl, ymax = maxEcl))
```

However, this is coerced into a loess smoothing, apparently due to the size of the data, which looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to feed geom_smooth specific pre-calculated values, or am I trying to use geom_smooth in very much the wrong way? It seems incongruous that the other geom_ arguments in ggplot2 are so adaptable and this seems so rigid.

The head and tail of the data source (a data table) is included below for structure purposes:

```
          iDate            off       trimAv   trimStD minEcl maxEcl   iMoYr iHrMi
   1: 2013-08 00:00     Production 136.52273 37.300389   76.4  218.4 2013-08 00:00
   2: 2013-08 00:30     Production 136.14091 36.117819   80.3  217.7 2013-08 00:30
   3: 2013-08 01:00     Production 133.92500 32.808662   76.9  213.3 2013-08 01:00
   4: 2013-08 01:30     Production 139.20476 37.929480   77.1  221.5 2013-08 01:30
   5: 2013-08 02:00     Production 137.82857 36.422042   74.9  221.0 2013-08 02:00
  ---                                                                             
1148: 2014-07 22:30 Non-Production  50.51250  3.025812   47.1   56.3 2014-07 22:30
1149: 2014-07 23:00 Non-Production  49.88571  2.066743   47.0   52.6 2014-07 23:00
1150: 2014-07 23:30 Non-Production  49.94286  2.318661   46.5   52.5 2014-07 23:30
1151: 2014-07 00:00 Non-Production  50.85714  2.860569   47.9   54.9 2014-07 00:00
1152: 2014-07 00:30 Non-Production  50.72857  4.181194   47.6   59.1 2014-07 00:30
```

If I can include the source data in a better/ more suitable form please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your aim is: What do you want to do with geom_smooth? Maybe you just need to set a value for the `method`-parameter?

Comment: Are you trying to show  minEcl and maxEcl as shading around each trimStD point or are do you first want to smooth the upper and lowers points using minEcl and maxEcl and then show the shadding?

Comment: Maybe you can try `geom_ribbon`? `+ geom_smooth(aes( x = iHrMi, ymin = minEcl, ymax = maxEcl))`, maybe together with `geom_lines`?

Comment: @WaltS, apologies, my headers seem to have come awry, will fix now and edit to clarify.

Comment: @Julian, apologies, will try and clarify in the following edit

Comment: In the above comment of course it should be `geom_ribbon(aes( x = iHrMi, ymin = minEcl, ymax = maxEcl))` instead of geom_smooth

Comment: @Julian, it is, thank you. If you put the answer in then I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `geom_ribbon`.

```
ggFacetProfile <- ggplot(sub, aes(group = iMoYr))  + 
  geom_line(aes(x= iHrMi, y = trimAv)) + 
  facet_grid(off ~ iMoYr, scales = "free") +
  ggtitle("Typical Half Hourly Profiles") + 
  xlab("Time") + ylab("Energy (kWh)") +
  geom_ribbon(aes( ymin = minEcl, ymax = maxEcl))
```